# PC performance is very bad even when RAM usage is very low (Windows 10)

Tags: performance

For the past few days, I noticed that my pc performance has been getting worse. I used to be able to play games smoothly, but now games are choppy even if the ram usage stays at 50%.
I have Avast Antivirus installed for a year now and I full scan my pc every month and all viruses have been removed.
I also formatted my pc as a last resort, but the problem still remains. I haven't installed Avast since then.
I used to have over 20 games installed. Currently, I have 4(not including games from Bluestacks).
Error checking says that there are no system errors.

My pc specs: Aspire 315-41

Processor   AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx     2.00 GHz

Installed RAM   8.00 GB (6.90 GB usable)

System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
[enter image description here][1]

HWiNFO things that if can't understand:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o88QN.png

Comment: How many games have you installed on your pc?

Comment: What's the **OS installed** on your pc? Windows? What's the **version**? Check that out by runnning the **winver** (if the OS's Windows) command and add to your question.

Comment: Please, also add information about the system storage of your computer and your RAM in more details using that program: [HWiNFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/)

Comment: Also check the Event Viewer in WIndows: Specifically if you see any errors (with RED icon) that refer to "disk" or NTFS. Let us know if there are errors.

Answer (score -1):

Try monitoring system vitals(Ram usage, CPU temps, CPU frequency, GPU temps, GPU frequency etc).

Maybe avast is hogging your cpu while playing games. Maybe your temps are getting high, maybe your CPU frequency is throttling(temp or power issue).

Also, A loose/old/about-to-die power plug/socket can create all sort of issues. It will spark under load and create voltage and current harmonics, which are very bad for the system.
Remove variables from the equation one by one.

Hopes this help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).